# Hooking CopyFile in Kernel32.dll makes recursive instances

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll, hook

My goal is to *weakly* monitor file movement.  I found a very easy [guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks) to create a global hook and got it to work just fine (note the need to compile both 64bit and 32bit versions, and putting them in different registry locations).  As a personal exercise, I wanted to hook CopyFile (chosen randomly from MoveFile, CreateFile, and all of their wonderful variants).  Following the exact same procedure from the guide, I came to this very short code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mhook/mhook-lib/mhook.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Defines and typedefs

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *CopyFileFP)(
    _In_  LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
    _In_  LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
    _In_  BOOL bFailIfExists
    );

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Original function

CopyFileFP OriginalCopyFile = (CopyFileFP)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "CopyFileW");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Hooked function

BOOL WINAPI HookedCopyFile(
    _In_  LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,
    _In_  LPCTSTR lpNewFileName,
    _In_  BOOL bFailIfExists
    )
{
    BOOL out = OriginalCopyFile(
                lpExistingFileName,
                lpNewFileName,
                bFailIfExists);

     char hello[] = "Hello\n";
     DWORD charsWritten = 0;

     WriteConsole(
         GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
         hello,
         6,
         &charsWritten,
         NULL);

    return out;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Entry point

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    __in HINSTANCE  hInstance,
    __in DWORD      Reason,
    __in LPVOID     Reserved
    )
{        
    switch (Reason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&OriginalCopyFile, HookedCopyFile);
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();
        Mhook_Unhook((PVOID*)&OriginalCopyFile);
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I wanted to see how the DLL was doing, so I needed some form of output.  I added a few console commands, however none of them use any spectacular functions (I don't do any string processing to print the source and destination filepaths).  After registering the dll and restarting a process (usually explorer.exe because it's so easy and only requires the 64bit dll), my dll seems to recursively call itself.

As mentioned before, the major difference between my code and the guide's code is the use of a console window.  The guide does state:

> As hooking is performed in DllMain of User32.dll you can call
>   functions only from Kernel32.dll and Ntdll.dll (other libraries are
>   not initialized yet).

However I have verified that [AllocConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [WriteConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [FreeConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [GetStdHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are all a part of Kernel32.dll.

**Why does this DLL recursively call itself?  How would I make sure to stop any continued calls, or what should I change to stop the recursiveness?**

On another note, my computer runs out of RAM really quickly when a globally hooked DLL recursively calls itself, even if each new console only consumes 2MB of memory. XD

Comment: Did you disable page file of windows?

Comment: That will let my dll crash when I run out of memory rather than having me race the opening consoles to see who is faster, but I don't think that will solve the main issue, and disabling it seems like a [bad idea](http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it).

Comment: You're passing a null pointer to `WriteConsole` for the `lpNumberOfCharsWritten` parameter. I don't know if that would cause the problems you're seeing but the docs don't say this parameter can be null so I'd start with that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I changed it to something I think is a little more correct (although the 6 might need to be a 7 for the null terminator), but I still get the same problem.  I don't *think* those inputs are the problem, but I can't be sure.  If something really was going catastrophically wrong there, I figured the DLL would crash before doing anything else.

Comment: Have you tried running the DLL inside a debugger to find out WHY it is being called recursively? Look at the call stack each time your hook is called. BTW, since you are hooking `CopyFileW()` only, you shouldn't be using `TCHAR` in your code. Use `WCHAR` instead. Otherwise hook `CopyFileA()` or `CopyFileW()` depending on what `TCHAR` actually maps to.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that it's safe to call `AllocConsole` during `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`?  DllMain is a rather delicate place...  Maybe internally it's doing something that should not be occurring during DllMain, like using critical section (though that would produce a hang IIRC).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I'm still relatively new to all of this, but I have not been able to successfully debug this DLL with `Debug`->`Attach to Process`; the DLL just never seems to load into `explorer.exe`.  The way I have been testing it is by flipping the registry entry `LoadAppInit_DLLs` and trying to do something in explorer (although silly, it does trigger the DLL consistently).

Comment: The sentence you've quoted is too general, here's a Best Practices doc from Microsoft when it comes to DllMain:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx) .  Instead can you try lazy initialization?  Call `AllocConsole` once on the first call to your hook function.

Answer (score 0):

Your dll can be called recursively. This is part of the OS design. Well, they designed it so. They never promised anybody opposite. You have to live with this.

I would recommend you to allocate TLS slot (TlsAlloc()/TlsFree, etc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801(v=vs.85).aspx) and mark that your dll is entered there. Using this mark you can break the recursion.

My own experience in hooking Windows functions shows that this is a tricky process. Form here you can call this and this, but not this. From somewhere else the picture is different. This is life.

Answer (score 0):

Copyfile is not used by explorer. It uses CopyFileEx since it has a progress callback routine to update the transfer status. Hang is occurring at the time of patching the call. Create a thread at the dllmain & do your patching on the thread routine.
Hooking is undocumented & unreliable method to monitor file movement. Windows has minifilter file system manager to which you can register callbacks & get notification on the file events. By this way, you can have a rock solid production code.